# while read loop seems to terminate after the first line, when using two pipes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, pipe, read

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

while read -r line
do
  echo "line via echo:"
  echo "$line"
  echo "line via sed:"
  sed 's/w/f/g' | sed 's/f/zzzzz/g' <<< "$line"
done < /dev/stdin
```

The above only seems to output a single line, and I'm not sure why?

```
printf "123\n456\n789" | ./srScript.sh
line via echo:
123
line via sed:
123
```

It seems to be the second `sed` in the pipe, it works as expected if i remove `sed 's/w/f/g' |`. But why does this happen - it seems like strange behaviour?

Comment: Where are you expecting the first sed to get its input from? did you perhaps intend to use [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) to redirect `"$line"` into the whole pipeline?

Comment: From `<<< "$line"`, and I'd assume it'd pipe the output to the second sed's input?

But yes `()` brackets seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You `sed` pipeline is a bit back to front:

```
sed 's/w/f/g' | sed 's/f/zzzzz/g' <<< "$line"
```

This would cause the first `sed` to read from standard input, i.e. your `456` and `789` strings, while the second `sed` would read `$line` (`123`).  The pipe would stop the output from the first `sed` from getting *anywhere* as the second `sed` is not reading from it.

I'm assuming you'd want the *first* `sed` to read the line, while the second `sed` reads the output of the first one.

You would do that with either

```
{ sed 's/w/f/g' | sed 's/f/zzzzz/g'; } <<< "$line"
```

or

```
sed 's/w/f/g' <<<"line" | sed 's/f/zzzzz/g'
```

Note also that in this case, you could combine the two `sed` calls into a single one:

```
sed 'y/w/f/; s/f/zzzzz/g' <<<"$line"
```

or,

```
sed -e 'y/w/f/' -e 's/f/zzzzz/g' <<<"$line"
```

I've additionally changed the first expression to use the `y` command which replaces single characters on the whole line.

However, it's *very seldom* a good idea to call `sed` for individual lines of input.  If you don't need the `echo` output, your script could be simplified into

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 'y/w/f/; s/f/zzzzz/g'
```

or even

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
y/w/f/
s/f/zzzzz/g
```